# Regex that finds consecutive or single words with first letter capitalized and aren't followed by a full stop

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that can identify in a sentence the consecutive or single words in a sentence start with capital letters, excluding words after a full stop, which includes `.,!?`

If we take the text below as an example:

```
It’s hard to say just what exactly Zendaya was wearing at the BET Awards today (some kind of sweatsuit dress?), but whatever it is, the 17-year-old looked stunning. In fact, she was probably the best dressed star on the red carpet – besides maybe Pharrell Williams, of course.

The “Replay” songstress was all smiles at the event despite new reports that she’s dropped out of Lifetime’s upcoming Aaliyah biopic. No official reason has been given yet, but considering all the problems and negativity that’s surrounded the TV movie since its announcement –including being unable to acquire the rights to Aaliyah’s music, and Aaliyah’s family rallying against the project– we’re not surprised to see Zendaya split.

Luckily Zendaya’s not short on work in the TV movie department: Her Disney channel movie ‘Zapped‘ recently premiered to 5.7 million viewers, making it the No.1 cable TV telecast among kids and tweens of 2014.

We’re bummed that she won’t be playing Aaliyah, but on the bright side, at least that means she’ll have more time to work on some new music.
```

I want to be able to retrieve the following:

```
Zendaya
BET Awards
Pharrell Williams
Replay
Lifetime’s
Aaliyah
TV
Aaliyah’s
Zendaya’s
Disney
Zapped
No
```

Can anyone suggest a regex for this one?

Comment: In what language? Also, is it important that `BET Awards` be a single match?

Comment: Why `It’s` is not in your list since it matches all of your criterias ?

Comment: I listed BET Awards as a single match, which means it was a single match.

Comment: It's wasn't listed, because the start of the text equals a full stop, sorry i haven't clarified that

Answer (score 2):

`(?<![?.,!]\s|^)((?:[A-Z][A-Za-z']+\s)*[A-Z][A-Za-z']+)`

Meaning

1. Find group that isn't preceded by the begin of line or punctuation
2. Match many with spaces and one without a space
3. Capital letter followed by letters or '

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eQ5sX7/3)

Comment: There are a few issues with this:
1. It select's only single words, doesn't select consecutive ones as one whole
2. Selects characters that aren't part of the word, for ex. identifies YouTube.” instead of Youtube
3. It does select words after full stop

Comment: he don't want to match IN.

Comment: I agree. It shouldn't match in.

Comment: This still matches `In`, `Lifetime's`, `Aaliyah's`, `Aaliyah's`, `Zendaya's`, `Her Disney`. (Note the difference in quotes.)

Comment: Does not match `In`. `Her Disney` should be matched by the criteria provided by the author.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve those results by following regex:

```
(?m)(?<!^|[.,!?] )([A-Z].*?)(?(?= [A-Z])\g1)(?=\W)
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sU9rZ2/2)